# Fill Datagrid from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a `Form1`, which contains a `DataGrid`, and a button `Search`. When I click the search button, another form (`Form2`) opens, with 2 textboxes and a button `Select`. When I click the button `Select`, I want the `DataGrid` of `Form1` to be filled by the values of the 2 textboxes in `Form2`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of data source do you use for the data grid on form1?

Comment: Im not using dataset or datasource nor binding source. I created the datagrid using drag and drop. I dont want to save the data in database. It is just for preview

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something. Your DataGrid uses some object as it's datasource, no matter if you have explicitly specified it, used data binding or any other way. I'm not quite familiar with the "drag-n-drop" technique of filling the DataGrid, could you please explain in more detail and post some code examples/screenshots (e.g. form designer, code-behind file etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of form2 you pass the Form as a parameter.

```
Form1 form;
public Form2(Form f)// Constructor
{
 form = f;
 IntializeComponent();
 }
```

Then you can call the Gridview of Form1 and add the textboxes you want to fill to it

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are storing the two `TextBox` values in `DataSet` or `DataTable`. If so then you can go with `DataGridView.Tag` property. This property holds the objects. In your case `DataSet` or `DataTable`.

**In Form2**

```
myDataGridView.Tag = myDataSet; //Storing the DataSet into DataGridView
```

**In Form1**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();  //Creating a new DataSet in Form1
ds = (DataSet)myDataGridView.Tag;  //assigning the Form2 myDataSet values to Form1 ds
```

*Note:* The DataGridView Modifier property should be set as **Public**.

Comment: Im not using dataset or datasource nor binding source. I created the datagrid using drag and drop. I dont want to save the data in database. It is just for preview

Comment: Then Instead of `DataSet` use `public string array` or whatever with you are ok.. just replace `DataSet` with your variable it will work. Dont forget to declare as public.