# passing data to datagridview using button

Tags: c#

i have a quick question i'm trying to make an application but i've faced a problem, i want to assign data to a button then pass that data to datagridview when the button is clicked ex.

[image]

```
private void TeaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sales.OrderDataGridView.Rows.Add(1, "Tea", 5.0);
        }
```

i expected it to pass the values inside the parentheses to the data grid view, but it returned a null reference error, the reason was "sales." it was returning null value, but i don't know any other way beside this .

Answer (score 0):

You must first define the DataGridView columns. you can use this code:

```
    public static Boolean isColumnsAdded = false;
    public static DataTable dt;
    private void TeaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
//It's better define the columns when loading the form-----------
            if (!isColumnsAdded)
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
                dt.Columns.Add("Type");
                dt.Columns.Add("Price");
                isColumnsAdded = true;
            }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Tea", 5.0);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string s = ex.Message;
        }
   }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: the datagrid is in a different form than the button .

Comment: the issue is when i call the datagrid or try to insert data to the datagrid it returns NullReferenceException because it's in another form, that's why i used ```sales.OrderDataGridView``` to call it from that form, and it still didn't help, i'm sad cuz after you trying to help, it didn't solve it .

Comment: i fixed the cause of the whole Null thing with this ```private static Sales sales = new Sales();```, but it doesn't return anything in the datagridview BTW: the datagrid is inside ```Sales```  Form .

Comment: @lostsoul You must submit the form as a constructor input to another form

Comment: i'm sorry, but can you explain for my simple mind ?

Comment: BTW : Why is this not ouputing anything                                                                      ```sales.OrderDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = amount;
            sales.OrderDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = Type;
            sales.OrderDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = price;                                Nor this            sales.OrderDataGridView.Rows.Add(amount, Type, price);```

Comment: @lostsoul see this link for pass the Form as a parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474565/fill-datagrid-from-another-form

Comment: your code worked it was my bad, i think it was something in my code,  Thank you so much .

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure:
is your datagridview is in the same form as the the tea button?
if so:

```
OrderDataGridView.Rows.Add("1", "Tea", "5.0")
```

and its better to have the values u want to add in " " unless you are going to use variables like :

```
string TeaStr = "Tea";
OrderDataGridView.Rows.Add("1", TeaStr, "5.0");
```

if you gonna use float variables, don't forget to add 'f':

```
float TeaPrice = 5.0f;
```

your friend mohamed from Egypt <3.